# How to execute existing WP Cron programmatically

Tags: wp-cron

I have a plugin that creates a WP cron when activated. It runs every hour.

I need to add a simple button somewhere in the dashboard for my client, that would trigger this cron. I don't want the client to do this from plugin's interface (e.g. Cron manager), which might seem too complex for him.

Is there a native WP method or an easy way to run a specific scheduled cron?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you register a scheduled event for WordPress' cron, the 3rd argument is a hook name:

```
wp_schedule_event( time(), 'hourly', 'my_hourly_event' );
```

And you add a function to run on this hook with `add_action()`:

```
add_action( 'my_hourly_event', 'do_this_hourly' );
```

This will cause `do_this_hourly()` to run whenever the scheduled event runs. This works because when the scheduled time occurs, your action is called like this:

```
do_action( 'my_hourly_event' );
```

Which causes anything hooked to `my_hourly_event` with `add_action()` to run. So you can run the hooked function, like `do_this_hourly()`, manually at any time by just manually triggering your event with `do_action()`, as above, such as in response to a form submission or AJAX request.

Alternatively, you can just run the hooked function directly:

```
do_this_hourly();
```

Comment: But this will not trigger the cron - it runs the logic associated with it. Depending on the specifics of OP's question, this might suffice. However if the cron is set to run at each full hour and I manually run it at x:55, it will run again at y:00 which might not be the desired.

Comment: True, but OP didn't specify that as an issue, and this is also what the plugins they refer to do when you trigger them manually.

Comment: I get what @kero is saying and it indeed might be a problem in some cases. However it is a sufficient solution for me, I don't know why I didn't think of this. Thanks.